# Terraform Sentinel Policy Resource not found

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform enterprise,

I created main.tf file and placed the below code for creating sentinel policy

```
data "tfe_workspace_ids" "all" {
  names        = ["*"]
  organization = myorg
}

locals {
  workspaces = "${data.tfe_workspace_ids.all.external_ids}" # map of names to IDs
}

resource "tfe_sentinel_policy" "test" {
  name         = "my-policy-name"
  description  = "This policy always passes"
  organization = "myorg"
  policy       = "main = rule { true }"
  enforce_mode = "hard-mandatory"
}
```

Then, when I run the terraform apply, the plan is success but apply fails with the below error message.

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # tfe_sentinel_policy.test will be created
  + resource "tfe_sentinel_policy" "test" {
      + description  = "This policy always passes"
      + enforce_mode = "hard-mandatory"
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + name         = "my-policy-name"
      + organization = "myorg"
      + policy       = "main = rule { true }"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions in workspace "tf-sentinel-governance"?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

tfe_sentinel_policy.test: Creating...

Error: Error creating sentinel policy my-policy-name for organization myorg: resource not found

  on main.tf line 10, in resource "tfe_sentinel_policy" "test":
  10: resource "tfe_sentinel_policy" "test" {
```

Comment: Could someone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that the `token` used for the `tfe` provider is a team token, and not an org token. I just ran in to a similar situation when trying to add `tfe_notification_configuration` to a workspace.